# square d q/o sub panel

Tags: subpanel

I had one breaker running kitchen and garage. I used skill saw and it blew breaker. I bought 2 new 20 amp breakers and separated lines. the garage on right side and kitchen on left. everything on right showed voltage but left side of panel had none. so I switched all to right . curious why this is and should I be concerned?

Comment: Hello, and welcome to Home Improvement. I'm guessing "yes, you should be concerned", but without more info (e.g. picture of inside of breaker box) we can't be sure. And, you should probably [take our tour](//diy.stackexchange.com/tour) so you'll know how best to participate here.

Comment: So you originally had a double pole breaker feeding outlets? If this is the case you had a multiwire branch circuit. Installing 2 separate breakers is a big code violation. If you had a single breaker feeding a sub panel and you used 2 separate breakers to feed that (another code violation) . Based on your description you need to do a lot of reading before burning your home down. We will need photos of the wiring, breakers wire sizes and what they power to be able to help but Yes you should be concerned.

Comment: Also, was the breaker 15A previously?  If so, you must not "upgrade" breakers like that! The wiring in the walls can't handle the overload!  Alternately, did the breaker have a "Test" button on it?

Comment: VTC The op has not been back and answered any questions so the question should be closed.